# How to use FormBuilder to pass id of object on update

Tags: angular

I am trying to update a row in database by passed ID.

I am having a form component, as you can see I am using reactive formBuilder:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'program-form',
  templateUrl: './program.form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./program.form.component.css']
})
export class ProgramFormComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  title: string;
  program: ProgramModel = new ProgramModel();

  constructor(
    formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {
    this.form = formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3)
      ]],
    //   email: ['', [
    //     Validators.required,
    //     BasicValidators.email
    //   ]],
    //   phone: [],
    //   address: formBuilder.group({
    //     street: ['', Validators.minLength(3)],
    //     suite: [],
    //     city: ['', Validators.maxLength(30)],
    //     zipcode: ['', Validators.pattern('^([0-9]){5}([-])([0-9]){4}$')]
    //   })
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    var id = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      var id = params['id'];

      this.title = id ? 'Edit' : 'New';

      if (!id)
        return;

      this.getProgram(id);
    });
  }

  private getProgram(id: number) {
        this.dataService.setEndpoint('/api/program/getsingle');
        this.dataService
            .GetSingle(id)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.program = data
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
  }

  create() {
    var result,
        userValue = this.form.value;

        console.log(userValue.Id + ", userValueId");

    if (userValue.id){
        this.dataService.setEndpoint('/api/program/update');
        result = this.dataService.Update(userValue.Id, userValue);
    } 
    else 
    {
        this.dataService.setEndpoint('/api/program/create');
        this.dataService.Create(userValue).subscribe(data => {
                (data => this.router.navigate(['users']));
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });;
    }

    //result.subscribe(data => this.router.navigate(['users']));
  }
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="row">
  <form materialize class="col s12" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="create()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
        <label for="name"
               [class.active]="program.name"
               data-error="Name is required and needs to contain at least 3 chars">
          Name
        </label>
        <input id="name" type="text" class="validate"
               [(ngModel)]="program.name" formControlName="name"
               [class.invalid]="form.controls['name'].touched && !form.controls['name'].valid">
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">
      Submit<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

How do I retrieve ID from this.form.value as you can see I am trying to get id, but console.log says it's undefined. Do I have to initialize it inside of form builder or inside of html?

Comment: Where is there are id? and I can't see anywhere you trying to pass it?`Am I blind :D

Comment: You are not even utilizing the formbuilder in your html?

Comment: Can you explain? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: You are not using the form at all in your template... there you should for example use `formControlName` :) Check my answer I just wrote for you :)

Answer (score 3):

You should actually utilize the reactive form you have created, now you have not done that in your html. When you build a form, you use the form controls in your html, and any possible form arrays and nested form groups. Here is a very simplified version of your code, where we can integrate the id very easily, we just decide not to even include it in the template! :)

You can use a boolean flag that doesn't show the form, until we have built it with the data you are receiving from db. Also we create a function, we call it to build the form. Let's call it `buildForm()` So your `getProgram` would call that in the callback (subscribe):

```ts
.subscribe(data => {
   this.program = data;
   this.buildForm(); // here!
}, ...
```

Then let's build the form!

```ts
buildForm() {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [this.program.id]
    name: [this.program.name]
  });
  this.isDone=true; // set boolean flag true so that the form will be shown!
}
```

And now to the form, where we actually utilize the form controls we have created. Here we can just exclude the form control `id`, it will still have the value, we just don't show it. Notice the use of `formControlName`:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="isDone" (ngSubmit)="create(form.value)">
  <input formControlName="name" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That's it! When you now console log the form value, it will also include the id.

Read more about reactive form, `formControl`:s, `FormArray`:s and `FormGroup`s from the **[official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html)**.

Finally a **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/xE8AyNkPy2jsKUfmi9OD?p=preview)** with the code I have described above :)

PS. In case you need to have an empty form, you can build it just like you have upon initialization of the component. Then when you have received data you can call a function and patch the values like so:

```html
this.form.patchValue({
  id: this.program.id,
  name: this.program.name
})
```

Then of course do not use the boolean flag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont have an Id on the form itself should the user input this Id or where do you get it from?

If you wanted to be on the form you would have to add to the form group like:

```
id: [id ||''],
name: ['', [...
```

Comment: I have a list of items, then I click Edit(so i get Id for each item). This id should be passed in edit form.

Comment: If you have the id when you create the form that code should work.

Comment: So I dont really get why do you want to add the id to the form if you are not gonna make any changes to it. But if you wanna do this remember to have the id before you create the form and build it like I showed you.

Comment: the point is where do I get that id in brackets from? how do I get it once I am in edit form? When I click save id is null, because I don't know how to get id passed into form object, then when I click save, from where to get that id VALUE or how to assign it..

Comment: Point is I get ID from database, and then I have list, for each row I have edit button, once edit button is clicked name is passed into textbox, but I want ID to be passed as well into object so I can use when updating values to database based on ID? Should id be exposed in hidden field or? ID should not be editable or insertable by user.

Comment: Then you dont need it to be via Id if when you click you go to a child component you can the @input to pass the object you need to edit if not you can use a service. Check this documentation for more information https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.htm